# ped.getGroup().size() weird behavior

Tags: anylogic

I encountered a weird behaviour of one of my groups, am I missing something?

The groups of 1 to 4 are approaching a pedOutput block where under first exit there is this condition:

```
ped.getGroup().size() <= 2 && v_table02_occupied < 20;
```

The condition works fine for some time, as I intended ( groups of <=2 exit with 1, otherwise exit 2), until the group of 4 approaches and comes through exit 1. I have no idea why.
It shouldn't be connected to `v_table02_occupied` variable, but so you know, at the time this group enters the pedOutput block it prints as 16.

[image: pedOutput with conditions]

Did someone see groups misbehaving like that before?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Did you traceln the group size in "on exit 2" as well as the value of that variable? Your confusion will probably dissolve once you do, probably is some logic error on your end :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately I still can't find the error...
I traced them all and exit 2 always shows groups above 2. My last reading before error:
`pedGroup size at exit 1 is 4`
`variable is 16`

Comment: what is the full condition for `v_table02_occupied` seems your screenshot is cut off there. And what do you mean by `variable` in your traceln? Make sure to be exact and specific here :)

Comment: Thanks for help :) 
So the full code in Condition 1 is `ped.getGroup().size() <= 2 && v_table02_occupied < 20;`
The `v_table02_occupied` variable is a simple integer in Main, with initial value 0. It's sole purpose was to limit number of pedestrians exiting through exit 1 (to 20).

Interestingly, the error repeated itself with different group (3 ped group), when I reshuffled simulation with different number of arrivals in pedSource. Meaning - the fact that it worked for so long with my initial experiment must have been coincidental and the entire thing does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `v_table02_occupied +1` code is executed *after* the condition check.

Best execute the code *before* the condition by using a simple delay of 0 duration in front of the `pedSelectOutput`. Call the `+1` code there in its "on enter" code box.

And then do some reading on how code is executed sequentially, this is a typical pitfall for many as it is so subtle :)

Comment: Many thanks Benjamin, that is good to know. I actually had a delay block in front of select output already for some other actions, so I can add this part there as well.

However, my issue still occurs and the problem remained. I might be wrong, but I don't see how the `v_table02_occupied` variable can have an impact here, as before checking that condition, the condition `ped.getGroup().size() <= 2` needs to be true - and it isn't, seeing that groups of 3 or 4 are checking this condition with `true` result. Maybe there is something wrong with that entire statement?
Thanks, Peter

Comment: fair, but I strongly suspect it is the same core issue. You will need to dig deeper yourself to get to the core of it by doing more tests and simplifying the setup. It is 99.999% not a bug but a misunderstanding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my part.

Condition statements seemingly should not end with `;`.

The statement that worked:

```
ped.getGroup().size() <= 2 && v_table02_occupied < 20
```

Instead of:

```
ped.getGroup().size() <= 2 && v_table02_occupied < 20;
```

Thanks Benjamin for taking time to help.
//Peter

Comment: See, told you to show us the full statement with a screenshot :D thx for sharing reply